# metafor, aggregate() data gives a different estimate than the multilevel model

Tags: r, aggregate, r-forestplot, metafor

I'm following [this](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:forest_plot_with_aggregated_values) guide to aggregate data at the study level for a meta-analysis i'm conducting.

Viechtbauer (at least i think it was him who wrote the article) says that "*When aggregating the estimates in this manner, it turns out that a meta-analysis of these pooled estimates yields exactly the same results as those obtained from the multilevel model above*"

Which is not what happens in my case.

I think the problem is that in his case, he was using
measure = "SMD" in escalc(), while i'm using "SMCR" for my meta-analysis.

```
df <- escalc(measure="SMCR", 
             m1i=me_post_int, 
             m2i=me_pre_int, 
             sd1i=sd_pre_int, 
             ni=num_int,
             ri=r_int_imp,
             data=df, 
             append=TRUE,  
             replace = F,
             var.names = c("yi_int", "vi_int")) 

df <- escalc(measure="SMCR", 
             m1i  = me_post_c,
             m2i  = me_pre_c, 
             sd1i = sd_pre_c, 
             ni   = num_c, 
             ri   = r_c_imp, 
             data = df, 
             append=TRUE, 
             replace = F,
             var.names = c("yi_c", "vi_c")) 

#reversing ES for outcomes with a negative direction
df$yi_int <- ifelse(df$direction == "neg", yes = df$yi_int*(-1), no = df$yi_int)
df$yi_c <- ifelse(df$direction == "neg", yes = df$yi_c*(-1), no = df$yi_c)


df$yi <- df$yi_int - df$yi_c

df$vi <- df$vi_int + df$vi_c
```

This is the code and output of the multilevel model, where df_pain is a subset of df:

```
pain_3lv<- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = ~ 1 | study_id/Unique_ID_ES, 
                  method="REML", data=df_pain)
pain_3lv

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 50; method: REML)

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed                 factor 
sigma^2.1  0.2641  0.5139     14     no               study_id 
sigma^2.2  0.0764  0.2764     50     no  study_id/Unique_ID_ES 

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 49) = 271.0640, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub     
  0.4517  0.1581  2.8568  0.0043  0.1418  0.7616  ** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And this is the code and output of the aggregated model:

```
agg <- aggregate(df_pain, cluster=study_id, V=vcov(pain_3lv, type="obs"),  addk=TRUE)

res <- rma(yi, vi, method="EE", data=agg, slab = study_id)
res

Equal-Effects Model (k = 14)

I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   79.70%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  4.93

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 13) = 64.0479, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub      
  0.3016  0.0475  6.3448  <.0001  0.2084  0.3948  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The difference in the method use to measure the effect sizes (SMD vs SMCR) is the only difference i can see in the code, i have otherwise copy-pasted his code. I used the "EE", equal effect model as prompted in the guide, but even if i try to use the same REML model, i still get a different estimate from the original one.

Comment: The effect size measure used is not relevant here. But I see nothing in your code to indicate why this doesn't work here. However, without a fully reproducible example, there is nothing further I can do to diagnose what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
So, a few things i tried: i updated my r version and the packages, i found out that Rstudio was still using R 4.3.1.

I tried to copy your exact code, and i get the correct results.

I tried checking the yi and vi of studies with only 1 outcome (the ones that were not aggregated), and the yi and vi remain the same. so i *think* that the aggregate function is working properly.

how can i provide a reproducible example without sharing my dataset?

Comment: small update: Since i'm using a subset of the full dataset, i've also tried to repeat each step without the subsetting, just in case, but i still get different results after aggregating the data.

Comment: Share a small piece of your full dataset that still illustrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, so, funny story. I wanted to create a subset of the dataset to share, so i did a subset with just the studies from 2014.
and the aggregate estimate was the same as the 3lvl model.
So i expanded the subset for all studies after 2010.
and the aggregate was the same as the 3lvl.
in the end i basically returned to the original dataset, but now IT WORKS.

The only thing i changed is that i only selected the relevant columns before aggregating, so, i don't know, maybe a column was being used instead of another for some reason?

Anyway, it works now.

Comment: Well, as long as it works now, all is good.